# Как решить проблему с TMPro?

Tags: c#, ui

При нажатии на "G" выводит такую ошибку: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Пытался найти имя объекта, чтобы вписать его перед каждым tmp, но не смог найти. Как решить?

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;




public class UI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text tmp;
    int health = 100;
    int damage = 20;
    int newhealth;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //TMP_Text tmp = new TMP_Text();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.G))
        {
            newhealth = health - damage;

            if (newhealth >= 50)
            {
                tmp.text = "Health: good";
            }
            if (newhealth <= 50)
            {
                tmp.text = "Health: bad";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не спец по Unity, так, чисто по документации говорю: `TMP_Text tmp = new TMP_Text();` - у вас должно быть либо через Unity установлен, либо через код ищите нужный компонент `= GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>();`. Далее, судя по документации, вы используете низкоуровневый `TMP_Text`, когда есть компоненты выше, например [TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.1/api/TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI.html), которые наследуются от того, что используете вы. И если судить по [таким ответам](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47763208/6808809), то это ваше решение.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь найти бы хорошую документацию по этому ugui, сколько не ищу, не могу найти

Comment: Ну, документация есть также, [на офф сайте](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/manual/index.html), только с версией смотрите внимательней (в верхнем левом углу выбирается).

Comment: Благодарю, посмотрим

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему использованием tmp.SetText() вместо tmp.text. Если есть решение проще -- я готов посмотреть.